# I have troubles with method in hereditary classes

Tags: java, object

I have a 2 class, one of which extends the superclass.
when I call the sub-class from the main, I get an error because "the method I call isn't a part of the class", but as my programme goes on, it should work
I had to use it only with the casting of class, but my teacher told me that casting should not be used in such a work, so please I'd like to understand where I'm wrong and where I can do better

(Im providing the code of 3 classes, the sub-class, the super-class, and the main)

Main

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Type in the number");
        int number = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Type in the name");
        String name = in.next();

        Test testObj = new Test(number);


        testObj = new TestSub(number);

        testObj.setNameSub(name);

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Super class

```
public class Test {

    protected int number;
    protected String name;

    public Test(int number){
        this.number=number;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "the name is "+name+"the number is "+number;
    }
}
```

Sub Class

```
public class TestSub extends Test {

    public TestSub(int number){
        super(number);
    }

    public void setNameSub(String name){
        setName(name);
    }

    public String toStringSub(){
        return toString();
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

> The method setNameSub(String) is undefined for the type Test

In the main where there is this instruction : `testObj.setNameSub(name);`

Comment: the error is quite obvious. Why do you even create that setNameSub or toStringSub method, that makes no sense at all. You instantiate it as a TestSub, but it is declared as a Test, so it is limited to the methods of Test

Comment: `testObj` is defined as a `Test` not a `TestSub`. I suggest to search for method inheritance, scope and casting.

Comment: thanks for help, to all, sorry for my low skill level, but tis chapter of java is kinda difficult, still thanks for everything <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is (as indicated in the comments) that you initialize testObj as Test instead of TestSub, causing the error when the compiler isn't able to find setNameSub() between Test's methods.

So the easy solution is clearly to initialize testObj as a TestSub.

The correct solution that takes advantage of the methods inheritance would be to keep the initialization as it is but to call the method testObj.setName(name) instead, and deleting setNameSub() and toString() methods from TestSub class since they don't add any difference from the methods in the Test class.